# count comma delimited list in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a column in Excel that contains a comma delimited list:

```
Header
A, B
A
A, B, C
D, A
```

I would like to extract this data so that I can count the occurrences of each item so that I would have the following results:

```
Count of Items
A    |    4
B    |    2
C    |    1
D    |    1
```

I am fine with hardcoding A, B, C, D in my list if necessary, but I have no clue what formula to use to count the items.

Comment: If none of the items are prefixes or suffixes of other items (that is, nothing like "A, B"; "AA, BA", etc.), then `=COUNTIF(range,"*"&RC[-1]&"*")` will work.

Comment: I was simplifying the example so there shouldn't be any prefixes like that. Go ahead and answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of the items are prefixes or suffixes of other items (that is, nothing like "A, B"; "AA, BA", etc.), then

```
=COUNTIF(range,"*"&RC[-1]&"*")
```

will work, where `range` is the source data (the 4 cells below `Header` in the example.)